# Is there a way to compress app design with react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I've design a todo app with react native and it's more than 200mb so i want to reduce to size.

i've tried [react-native-compressor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-compressor?activeTab=readme) but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open up `android/app/build.gradle`
- Set def    `enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true` this would enable
  Progaurd to    compress the Java Bytecode. This reduces the app size
  by a tad bit
- Set `def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true` . Android
  devices support two major device artitectures `armebi` and `x86`. By
  default RN builds the native librariers for both these artitectures
  into the same apk.

for more info : [click here](https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640)

---

Hope this was helpful .